Vba moving files form a to b via fso object
I have a list of beginnings of filesnames in excel ,
I want to make a macro that will move them from one defined directory to the other
The file name are named like this AAAAXXX
AAAA- are unique numbers that i will put in excel
XXX- are also unique number but i want macro to skip them while moving/copying files
I tried using * after the file name but it read it as part of file name and not as a wildcard
I found out that Fso.Movefile doesnt work when i put variable in it . how can i solve it ?
Or i do need to use other command
Is it possible to do it without using library?
Sub movingfilename()
    Dim a As String
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim locationstart As String
    Dim locationend As String
    Dim filename As String
    Dim notfoundfiles As New Collection
    Dim message As String
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    locationstart = "G:\Test\start\" & filename
    locationend = "G:\Test\stop\" & filename

    For Each cell In Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(-4162).Row)
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
        filename = cell.Value
        fso.MoveFile "G:\Test\start\filename*", "G:\Test\stop\"
    End If
    Next cell
End Sub



I want to move file from place a to place b. I have beginning of their names and want excel to move them ignoring rest of their name

Your code isn't working because you are incorrectly constructing your code arguments, not because it won't take a variable.
Adapt the following working code to your other requirements. The code as written has no error checking or checking for missing files in start or duplicate files in end:
Please note my preferences:

the use of Option Explicit (you can google for what that does)
not relying on ActiveSheet when setting your range but explicitly stating the workbook and worksheet.
not using a variable name that is very similar to a property name (eg: cell vs cells vs c)
using column and row numbers instead of alphabetical column names (easier to keep track of things).
Early binding for the filesystem object is a bit more efficient, but can be problematic if you have to distribute the macro, so I would not object to the late binding you show in your code

Option Explicit
Sub movingFilename()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim locationStart As String
    Dim locationEnd As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim c As Range
    
    
locationStart = "G:\Test\start\"
locationEnd = "G:Test\end\"

Set fso = New FileSystemObject

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet5")
    For Each c In Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        If Not IsEmpty(c) Then
            fileName = c.Value & "*"
            fso.MoveFile locationStart & fileName, locationEnd
        End If
    Next c
End With
            
End Sub


So i copied your code , and adjusted it but i get path not found error 76 . i want to move  930111113.xml file i put in excel in right cell 9301 . In locals menu it show filename value as "9301*" so why wnot it work

@MrPazur1 Hard to say without more information. One possible explanation is that locationEnd is incorrect.  If you can't find the issue, suggest you edit your question by adding a section where you reproduce the code you are using, as well as doing a copy/paste of the folder path from the properties dialog.

Move File Matching Pattern

This will overwrite any existing files!!!

Sub MoveFilesMatchingPattern()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Move Files Matching Pattern"
    Const SRC_FOLDER_PATH As String = "G:\Test\start\"
    Const DST_FOLDER_PATH As String = "G:\Test\stop\"
    Const DST_OVERWRITE_FILES As Boolean = True ' do not modify!
    
    ' Reference the range.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim rg As Range:
    Set rg = ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    
    ' Return the unique values from the range in the keys of a dictionary
    ' and a 'False' for each corresponding item (value).
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim cell As Range, FilePattern As String
    
    For Each cell In rg.Cells
        FilePattern = CStr(cell.Value) & "*"
        If Len(FilePattern) > 1 Then
            dict(FilePattern) = False
        End If
    Next cell
    
    ' For each file in the source folder, loop through
    ' the elements of the dictionary.
    ' Using the 'Like' operator, attempt to find a match.
    ' For each match, copy the source file to the destination folder
    ' overwriting existing files, delete the source file, 
    ' and set the corresponding Boolean
    ' in the items of the dictionary to 'True',
    
    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Dim fsoFile As Object, Key As Variant, MovedFilesCount As Long
    
    For Each fsoFile In fso.GetFolder(SRC_FOLDER_PATH).Files
        For Each Key In dict.Keys
            With fsoFile
                If .Name Like Key Then ' pattern matched; case-sensitive
                    .Copy DST_FOLDER_PATH, DST_OVERWRITE_FILES
                    .Delete
                    dict(Key) = True
                    MovedFilesCount = MovedFilesCount + 1
                    Exit For
                End If
            End With
        Next Key
    Next fsoFile
    
    ' Loop through the elements of the dictionary and remove each element
    ' whose corresponding item is set to 'True'.
    For Each Key In dict.Keys
        If dict(Key) Then dict.Remove Key
    Next Key
    
    ' Inform.
    
    Dim MsgMoved As String: MsgMoved = MovedFilesCount & " file" _
            & IIf(MovedFilesCount = 1, "", "s") & " moved."
    
    If dict.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox MsgMoved & vbLf & vbLf & "All patterns matched.", _
            vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    Else
        MsgBox MsgMoved & vbLf & vbLf & "No files matching the following " _
            & dict.Count & " pattern" & IIf(dict.Count = 1, "", "s") _
            & " found:" & vbLf & vbLf & Join(dict.Keys, vbLf), _
            vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    End If

End Sub

